# asymptotic behavior of the solution of an ordinary differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I am a civil engineer with basic mathematics skills and need help for the following - perhaps simple - problem.

Consider the following autonomous system of two non-linear ordinary differential equations for the unknown functions $y_1$ and $y_2$:
$$dy_1/dt = P(y_2) * ( Q(y_2)-y_1 )$$
$$dy_2/dt = y_1$$
with the initial conditions

$$y_1(0) = y_2(0) = 0$$

Assume that the functions $P(y_2)$ and $Q(y_2)$ have the following properties:

$$P(y_2) > 0,  dP/dy_2 <0, \lim_{y_2\rightarrow ∞} P = P_∞ = constant >> 0 $$
$$Q(y_2) > 0,  dQ/dy_2 >0, \lim_{y_2\rightarrow ∞} Q = Q_∞ = constant >> 0 $$

I "feel" that

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow ∞} y_1 = Q_∞  $$

Is that correct? And, if yes, how can I prove that?

Comment: This is a forum for research level math. You'd have better luck on math stack exchange.